# Is it possible to make interactive image editor in Ext JS 6.0?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Since I am a beginner in Ext JS, I was wondering whether it is possible to develop interactive image editor where user can do following things :

1. Add/remove custom shapes over canvas using drag and drop
2. Edit: resize, rotate, crop, etc.
3. Group/Ungroup shapes that are present on canvas
4. Perform operations at pixel level
   etc.

I know, libraries like '*fabric.js*' provide these features. Is it possible (and easy) to implement those features without using '*fabric.js*' in Ext JS ? I see, there is an API class `Ext.draw.sprite` in Ext JS.

For example:
If I want to add drag/resize boundary around an object (using which user can easily rotate/resize/move the object), is it easy enough to implement in extjs or will I need to write this feature from scratch ?

Comment: Of course there is. The question is how long it takes. You can always reinvent the wheel, you know?

Comment: yes, obviously. What I mean is, does extjs provide these features ? or will I need to implement this from scratch (i.e. extjs won't be of any help) 
 ?

Comment: Ext will be of little help, you're best off wrapping something else.

Comment: Do you have any idea whether it will be OK to use `fabric.js` with `Ext JS` ?